# How to write filter for this array to display proper format in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am getting response from backend like

```
[
{"name":"logo2.png",
"caption":"ll",
"path":"images\/bussiness\/images\/logo2.png",
"status":"1",
"pract_image_id":4,
"image_identifier":"2",
"branch_id":2
},
{"name":"Image3.png",
"caption":"dd",
"path":"images\/bussiness\/images\/Image3.png",
"status":"1",
"pract_image_id":5,
"image_identifier":"1",
"branch_id":2
},
{"name":"Logo2.jpg",
"caption":"",
"path":"images\/business\/images\/Logo2.jpg",
"status":"0",
"pract_image_id":2,
"image_identifier":"2",
"branch_id":2
},
{"name":"Image1.png",
"caption":"img",
"path":"images\/bussiness\/images\/Image1.png",
"status":"0",
"pract_image_id":3,
"image_identifier":"1",
"branch_id":2
}
]
```

Above Json some objects are Logos of company, some are Images of companys.

In above json says
            `"image_identifier"->1-Image,2-Logo
                   "Status": 1-Active,2-inActive`

I want to show Images  like

```
       Image-Identifier     Status
            2                1(current Acitve Logo)
            1                1(current Active Image)
            2                0(Inactive logo)
            1                0(inactive image)
```

How to filter this array to display .Please help me to do it.

Comment: You don't need a filter, but a custom [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that renders the result as you want it.

Comment: please tell me how to write directive

Comment: I linked to the documentation that explains how. Google it and there are hundreds if not thousand tutorials.

Comment: If she asks 1 more, I will vote the question down! ;-/